# Graph is not showing magento admin dashboard

Tags: magento-1.8, open-graph

My Magento having over 1 lakh products orders, but graph not showing according to sale on magento admin dashboard.
please help me what i need to do.
Graph showing blank. no graph image is showing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: first you should check internet Connection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go To

> app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Dashboard\Graph.php

Check your api url,

```
 const API_URL = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart';
```

Change code for API URL, and then re-index.

Answer (score 9):

**Here the Solution**

Edit the file at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/graph.phtml

Find this line ***getChartUrl(false)*** change to  ***getChartUrl(true)***

Comment: this one works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [this site](http://www.phpro.be/news/magento-dashboard-charts-not-working)

> **Solution 1**:
>
> Allow access to this URL on your firewall:
>   http://chart.apis.google.com/chart

or

> **Solution 2**:
>
> Make sure Magento does not try to fetch the image through
>   PHP Locate this file:
>   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/graph.phtml
>   And change: "getChartUrl()" to "getChartUrl(true)"
>
> This will cause Magento to just return the image location at
>   http://chart.apis.google.com/chart instead of downloading it through
>   PHP.

Both solutions seem to work great. But Solution 2 could throw a warning if you are running your Magento back-end on an SSL connection (which should be doing by the way!)

After implementing this solution the Magento charts or graphs are shown and you can again admire your sales figures!

Comment: Thanks for answer , sorry buddy but i also go through this link , actully error is the image created by magento ajax function for graph in base 64 bit is not correct. please specify this.

Comment: Ah, sorry. You should edit your question to specifically target that question.

Comment: Question is simple dude, that graph is not showing on magento admin dashboard

Answer (score 1):

In case you've been googling this in 2019 - this is an issue with deprecated Google Image Chart API. There is a Magento 1 module that fixes missing charts - https://github.com/onilab/magento-1-google-api-chart-fix

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just related to 24 Hours Chart it can be cased by minimal allowed GET variable length settings of suhosin as Titan Lee described on his blog:

This is related to the minimal allowed GET variable length settings. Check your settings for suhosin:

```
Add/Edit line - > suhosin.get.max_value_length = 1024
```

So, edit: `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/suhosin.ini`
If the above file doesn't exist for you. Then locate & edit, `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`

http://titanlee.com/my-stuffs/geekystuffs/solved-magento-dashboard-chartgraph-broken/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else bumps into it ....

For me it was modsecurity blocking the request because it was detecting multiple URL encoding.  It was rule 950109 in our default WHM config.