# Magento Sales Graph issue after upgrading to 1.8.1.0 from 1.5.1.0

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, ce-1.8.1.0, upgrade

I have upgraded Magento from Version 1.5.1.0 to 1.8.1.0
And now the order graph in the admin dashboard is showing misleading data. The number of sales has shifted by 2 months considering what it was in 1.5 version.

To be specific, in the earlier version of Magento the sales in my website reached peak on August and now after upgrade the peak is shown on September.

When I try to debug, the data coming the database seems to be correct but somehow the chart is displaying incorrectly.

Has anybody come across this issue and is there anyone who can help me with this??

Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

**Here the Solution**

Edit the file at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/graph.phtml

Find this line

```
"getChartUrl(false)"
```

change to

"getChartUrl(true)"

Answer (score 0):

This code needs to be change in api url.

```
const API_URL = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart';
```

I think this [LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23881/graph-is-not-showing-magento-admin-dashboard/23894#23894), may be your answer